# {mailing.viewUrl} returns faulty URL

Tags: tokens

When I click on the {mailing.viewUrl} inside an email the URL formed is as follows:

www.http.com//www.example.com.au......

I am not sure why the www.http.com is replacing http:

Cheers
Martin Fuggle

Comment: What about the other urls, like subscribeURL or optoutURL. If in all urls i suspect something wrong in the general token url formation

Comment: Unsubscribe and Opt Out URLs function correctly. It is only the mailing.viewUrl that returns the faulty URL

Comment: in 4.6.2 this is a code issue, see:
http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3057/is-there-a-bug-when-placing-a-token-inside-quotation-marks-in-civimail-4-6-2

Answer (score 1):

Ooops - my mistake. I had included "http://" in the href before the token. Sorry for the trouble and the answers

Comment: so its fixed, right? Might want to comment and edit the original post

Comment: @DonaldLobo Since the question and answer might be helpful to others, I believe proper StackExchange protocol is to [accept this answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). If the question/answer pair is not helpful, then Martin should delete the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Resource URL Settings (**Administer menu > System Settings > Resource URLs**).  I'd guess that you'll see an setting there containing a malformed URL.

If not, please update your question with your version number and the values you see in that screen.

Comment: Resource URLs are just fine. Version is 4.5.8