# Is there a bug when placing a token inside quotation marks in CiviMail 4.6.2+?

Tags: civimail, tokens, issues

I have a mailing template with this snippet:

```
Trouble seeing this email? <a href="{mailing.viewUrl}">Read in your browser</a>.
```

In previous versions of CiviCRM, the token would render correctly.

In 4.6.2 and 4.6.3, the token renders, but elements of it are HTML-escaped.  More importantly, the quotation marks surrounding the token are HTML-escaped:

```
Trouble seeing this email? <a href=&quot;http://mysite.org/civicrm/mailing/view?reset=1&amp;id=6&quot;>Read in your browser</a>.
```

My workaround has been to add a space between the quotation mark and token, which renders correctly:

```
Trouble seeing this email? <a href=" http://mysite.org/civicrm/mailing/view?reset=1&id=7 ">Read in your browser</a>.
```

Has anyone else seen this behavior?  I can't send mailings from the demo server, and setting up my dev environment to send e-mails would be a serious pain, so I wanted to check in with the community before reporting it on issues.civicrm.org.  My guess is that some of you have already got e-mails sitting in your inbox that you can test by clicking a link.

Answer (score 3):

in CiviCRM 4.6.2 you can patch this issue with the following edit:

```
--- a/a/civicrm-core/CRM/Mailing/BAO/Mailing.php
+++ b/b/civicrm-core/CRM/Mailing/BAO/Mailing.php
@@ -1472,7 +1472,7 @@ ORDER BY   civicrm_email.is_bulkmail DESC
       if ($this->url_tracking) {
         $data = CRM_Mailing_BAO_TrackableURL::getTrackerURL($token, $this->id, $event_queue_id);
         if (!empty($html)) {
-          $data = htmlentities($data);
+          $data = htmlentities($data, ENT_NOQUOTES);
         }
       }
       else {
```

Comment: This was fixed in 4.6.4 - via this pull request: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/5904

Answer (score 2):

I actually found another 4.6.3 site that exhibited identical behavior, so I filed an issue: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16634